# Access class attributes in python from class method

Tags: python, class, attributes, decorator, class-method

Assuming I have the following class:

```
class Foo:
 bar : str
 @classmethod
 def foobar(self): #self = cls
  print(??)
```

And I want to print the attribute `bar` in `foobar`.
How do I do that? `self.bar` gives me the error:

> `AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'bar'`

How do I do that?

Comment: it looks like you only assigned an annotation to the variable, but did not actually define a value. The `bar: str` syntax only assigns an annotation of `str` to the variable, which also appears in the `__annotations__` variable

Answer (score 3):

Following is the way

```
class Foo:
    bar: str = None  # Initialize your attribute in this way

    @classmethod
    def foobar(cls):  # self = cls
        print(cls.bar) 


a = Foo()
a.foobar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the str isn't assigned an actual value.

You should also indent with 4 spaces, not 1.

Comment: I think "Str isn't an actual value" is a bit misleading (types are values too in Python). Rather, the issue is that `bar : str` is a type annotation, which doesn't assign a value to `bar`, only declares the type `bar` is expected to have.

Comment: You are right. But it still doesn't have an actual string, just the declaration of a string.